# Count characters between two empty space to dashes() in vba

Tags: vba

How do I get the length of character between beginning with space and ending with * Here is the image. Column B shows the total len before dasher(-) and my code

[image]

```
Sub xn()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1
    If Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A"& x).len(Right," ") Or _
    Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A"&x)len(Left,"-") Then
        len(totallen)
    End If
    x = x + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: You screen shot is not very informative. As for your code, it has many issues. Please post a better screen shot and the actual result you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted has multiple issues:

1. `Worksheet` is not a valid object - you need to use `Worksheets`.
2. `.len` is not a property of a Range object.
3. Even in `.len` was a property of a Range, you would need a
   de-reference operator (aka '.') in here: `Range("A"&x)len(Left,"-")`
4. If you intend to use the function `Len()`, it only takes one argument.
5. You apparently are trying to loop, but you need to use either a For
   or For Each loop - it won't loop automatically when you increment x
   at the bottom of the sub.
6. `Right` is a function, but you're calling it without arguments and they are not optional.
7. Similarly, `Left` is a function, but you're also calling it without
   the required arguments.
8. `totallen` is not declared anywhere, so `Len(totallen)` will assume
   that totallen is a Variant (default for undeclared variables), then
   cast it to a String, and then always return 0 because it has never
   been given a value.
9. Anything else I may have missed.

The solution is to use the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  It returns the location in a string of a given sub-string.

```
Sub xn()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 1 To sheet.Range("A" & sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        sheet.Cells(x, 2) = InStr(1, sheet.Cells(x, 1), "-") - 1
    Next x

End Sub
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at the MSDN article on [Looping Through a Range of Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (2003 vintage, but still valid), and [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba).

Comment: @Comintem thanks working fine but can you explain me second line please what does -1 and are you starting from 0 or 1 i see the dashes but where is the start point

Comment: @user3713336 - InStr is 1 based, so the first parameter is to start from the first character in the cell.  It returns the position of what you are searching, so to get a count of characters up to that point you have to subtract 1. For example, `xxxx-xxxx` would return 5 because '-' is the 5th character.